# Multiple file uploads in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, file-upload, sinatra

I'm writing a simple Sinatra app but having issues having `<input type="file" multiple />` not making Rack throw a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'bytesize' for (Hash)` while reading the files.

The form is written like so:

```html
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple />
</form>
```

But the receiving end throws the mentioned error, **before any of my code executes**, that is, Rack is not parsing correctly the `input[name=images]`. Am I sending the form incorrectly? If I drop the brackets `[]`, then only the last file (of many) is sent, but I feel like I might be missing something...

Just to clarify: this is Sinatra v1.4.3 and Rack v1.5.2, the latter being the one throwing the exception. Full backtrace [here](http://pastebin.com/h8eLWKKP).

Comment: The error is in Ruby code somewhere. You'll need to post the action source and any other relevant code.

Comment: Yes, it's specifically on Rack's [utils.rb](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L333), as I've said, it doesn't reach my code. I was hoping my array-type field was the problem.

Comment: No code? Also, that doesn't appear to be the *full* backtrace. Where's the exception?

Comment: No code since the exception DOES NOT touch my code, that is, its thrown by Rack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing that puts me off here is that you don't use the POST method – maybe your issue has to do with that. Anyway, the following code works perfectly for me. I hope this will give you a hint how to fix your code.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  <<-HTML
  <html>
  <head><title>Multi file upload</title></head>
  <body>
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  HTML
end

post '/upload' do
  content_type :text

  res = "I received the following files:\n"
  res << params['images'].map{|f| f[:filename] }.join("\n")
  res
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Patrick! I just copied and pasted incorrectly, I'll update the question to reflect this. Just out of curiosity, which Rack/Sinatra versions are you using?

Comment: You're welcome! I used Rack 1.5.2 and Sinatra 1.4.3 on MRI 2.0.0p195 to test the code.

Comment: I just tried it out with MRI 1.9.3-p429 and this works as well.

Comment: This is weird, been debugging for a couple of days, but never thought a simple nginx restart would solve the issue. Will marks as answered since you've been quite helpful, and this might help others.